# Is there a way to prevent a move constructor followed by a move assignment operator when copy elison fails?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I've a situation where I want to call a function with a parameter and return the result into this same argument

```c++
foo = f(foo);
```

In addition, I assume that the parameter `x` is very large, so I don't want to call its copy constructor, but rather its move constructor.  Finally, I don't want to pass the argument by reference because I would like to compose the function `f` with another function `g`.  Hence, so that things like

```c++
foo = g(f(foo));
```

are possible.  Now, with move semantics, this is all mostly possible as demonstrated by the following program

```c++
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo() {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl; 
    } 
    Foo(Foo && x) {
        std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(Foo const & x) {
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo & operator = (Foo && x) {
        std::cout << "move assignment" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
    Foo & operator = (Foo & x) {
        std::cout << "copy assignment" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
};

Foo f(Foo && foo) {
    std::cout << "Called f" << std::endl;
    return std::move(foo);
}

Foo g(Foo && foo) {
    std::cout << "Called g" << std::endl;
    return std::move(foo);
}

int main() {
   Foo foo;
   foo = f(std::move(foo));
   std::cout << "Finished with f(foo)" << std::endl;
   foo = g(f(std::move(foo)));
   std::cout << "Finished with g(f(foo))" << std::endl;
}
```

The output from this program is:

```
constructor
Called f
move
move assignment
destructor
Finished with f(foo)
Called f
move
Called g
move
move assignment
destructor
destructor
Finished with g(f(foo))
destructor
```

which makes sense.  Now, what's bothering me is that when we call `f` the first time, or the composition, the move constructor is followed by the move assignment operator.  Ideally, I'd like to use copy elison to prevent any of these constructors from being called, but I'm not sure how.  Specifically, the functions `f` and `g` call `std::move` on `foo` because otherwise the copy, not move, constructor is called.  This is specified in the C++ standard under section 12.8.31 and 12.8.32.  Specifically,

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit
>   the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor
>   selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the
>   object have side effects. In such cases, the implementation treats the
>   source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two
>   different ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of
>   that object occurs at the later of the times when the two objects
>   would have been destroyed without the optimization. This elision of
>   copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the
>   following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple
>   copies):
>
> — in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when
>   the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other
>   than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cvunqualified
>   type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be
>   omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the
>   function’s return value

Since we return a function argument, we don't get copy elison.  In addition:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be
>   met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter,
>   and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload
>   resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed
>   as if the object were designated by an rvalue. If overload resolution
>   fails, or if the type of the first parameter of the selected
>   constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object’s type (possibly
>   cv-qualified), overload resolution is performed again, considering the
>   object as an lvalue. [ Note: This two-stage overload resolution must
>   be performed regardless of whether copy elision will occur. It
>   determines the constructor to be called if elision is not performed,
>   and the selected constructor must be accessible even if the call is
>   elided. —end note ]

Since we return a function argument, we return an l-value, so we're forced to use `std::move`.  Now, at the end of the day, I just want the memory moved back into the argument and calling both a move constructor and move assignment operator seems like too much.  It feels like there should be a single move or copy elison.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

## Edit 1

In a longer response to @didierc's answer than a comment would allow, technically, yes, that would work for this situation.  At the same time, the greater goal is to allow functions with multiple returns to be composed together in a way where nothing is copied.  I can also do this with move semantics, but it requires a trick from C++14 to work.  It also exacerbates the issue with lots of moves.  However, technically, there's no copies.  Specifically:

```c++
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

// This comes from the N3802 proposal for C++
template <typename F, typename Tuple, size_t... I>
decltype(auto) apply_impl(F&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}
template <typename F, typename Tuple>
decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, Tuple&& t) {
    using Indices = 
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>;
    return apply_impl(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t), Indices{});
}

// Now, for our example
struct Foo {
    Foo() {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl; 
    } 
    Foo(Foo && x) {
        std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(Foo const & x) {
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo & operator = (Foo && x) {
        std::cout << "move assignment" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
    Foo & operator = (Foo & x) {
        std::cout << "copy assignment" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
};

std::tuple <Foo,Foo> f(Foo && x,Foo && y) {
    std::cout << "Called f" << std::endl;
    return std::make_tuple <Foo,Foo> (std::move(x),std::move(y));
}

std::tuple <Foo,Foo> g(Foo && x,Foo && y) {
    std::cout << "Called g" << std::endl;
    return std::make_tuple <Foo,Foo> (std::move(x),std::move(y));
}

int main() {
   Foo x,y;
   std::tie(x,y) = f(std::move(x),std::move(y));
   std::cout << "Finished with f(foo)" << std::endl;
   std::tie(x,y) = apply(g,f(std::move(x),std::move(y)));
   std::cout << "Finished with g(f(foo))" << std::endl;
}
```

This generates

```
constructor
constructor
Called f
move
move
move assignment
move assignment
destructor
destructor
Finished with f(foo)
Called f
move
move
Called g
move
move
move assignment
move assignment
destructor
destructor
destructor
destructor
Finished with g(f(foo))
destructor
destructor
```

Basically, the same issue as above occurs: We get move assignments that would be nice if they disappeared.

## Edit 2

Per @MooingDuck's suggestion, it's actually possible to return an rref from the functions.  Generally, this would be a really bad idea, but since the memory is allocated outside of the function, it becomes a non-issue.  Then, the number of moves is dramatically reduced.  Unfortunately, if someone tries to assign the result to an rref, this will cause undefined behavior.  All of the code and results are below.

For the single argument case:

```c++
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    // Add some data to see if it gets moved correctly
    int data;

    Foo() : data(0) {
        std::cout << "default constructor" << std::endl; 
    } 
    Foo(int const & data_) : data(data_) {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl; 
    } 
    Foo(Foo && x) {
        data = x.data;
        std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(Foo const & x) {
        data = x.data;
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo & operator = (Foo && x) {
        data = x.data;
        std::cout << "move assignment" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
    Foo & operator = (Foo & x) {
        data = x.data;
        std::cout << "copy assignment" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
};

Foo && f(Foo && foo) {
    std::cout << "Called f: foo.data = " << foo.data << std::endl;
    return std::move(foo);
}

Foo && g(Foo && foo) {
    std::cout << "Called g: foo.data = " << foo.data << std::endl;
    return std::move(foo);
}

int main() {
    Foo foo(5);
    foo = f(std::move(foo));
    std::cout << "Finished with f(foo)" << std::endl;
    foo = g(f(std::move(foo)));
    std::cout << "Finished with g(f(foo))" << std::endl;
    Foo foo2 = g(f(std::move(foo)));
    std::cout << "Finished with g(f(foo)) a second time" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "foo2.data = " << foo2.data << std::endl;
    // Now, break it.
    Foo && foo3 = g(f(Foo(4)));  
    // Notice that the destuctor for Foo(4) occurs before the following line.
    // That means that foo3 points at destructed memory.
    std::cout << "foo3.data = " << foo3.data << ".  If there's a destructor"
        " before this line that'd mean that this reference is invalid."
        << std::endl;
}
```

This generates

```
constructor
Called f: foo.data = 5
move assignment
Finished with f(foo)
Called f: foo.data = 5
Called g: foo.data = 5
move assignment
Finished with g(f(foo))
Called f: foo.data = 5
Called g: foo.data = 5
move
Finished with g(f(foo)) a second time
foo2.data = 5
constructor
Called f: foo.data = 4
Called g: foo.data = 4
destructor
foo3.data = 4.  If there's a destructor before this line that'd mean that this reference is invalid.
destructor
destructor
```

In the multi-argument case

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

// This comes from the N3802 proposal for C++
template <typename F, typename Tuple, size_t... I>
decltype(auto) apply_impl(F&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}
template <typename F, typename Tuple>
decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, Tuple&& t) {
    using Indices = 
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>;
    return apply_impl(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t), Indices{});
}

// Now, for our example
struct Foo {
    // Add some data to see if it gets moved correctly
    int data;

    Foo() : data(0) {
        std::cout << "default constructor" << std::endl; 
    } 
    Foo(int const & data_) : data(data_) {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl; 
    } 
    Foo(Foo && x) {
        data = x.data;
        std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(Foo const & x) {
        data = x.data;
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo & operator = (Foo && x) {
        std::cout << "move assignment" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
    Foo & operator = (Foo & x) {
        std::cout << "copy assignment" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
};

std::tuple <Foo&&,Foo&&> f(Foo && x,Foo && y) {
    std::cout << "Called f: (x.data,y.data) = (" << x.data << ',' <<
        y.data << ')' << std::endl;
    return std::tuple <Foo&&,Foo&&> (std::move(x),std::move(y));
}

std::tuple <Foo&&,Foo&&> g(Foo && x,Foo && y) {
    std::cout << "Called g: (x.data,y.data) = (" << x.data << ',' <<
        y.data << ')' << std::endl;
    return std::tuple <Foo&&,Foo&&> (std::move(x),std::move(y));
}

int main() {
    Foo x(5),y(6);
    std::tie(x,y) = f(std::move(x),std::move(y));
    std::cout << "Finished with f(x,y)" << std::endl;
    std::tie(x,y) = apply(g,f(std::move(x),std::move(y)));
    std::cout << "Finished with g(f(x,y))" << std::endl;
    std::tuple <Foo,Foo> x_y = apply(g,f(std::move(x),std::move(y)));
    std::cout << "Finished with g(f(x,y)) a second time" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(x.data,y.data) = (" << std::get <0>(x_y).data << ',' <<
        std::get <1> (x_y).data << ')' << std::endl;
    // Now, break it.
    std::tuple <Foo&&,Foo&&> x_y2 = apply(g,f(Foo(7),Foo(8)));  
    // Notice that the destuctors for Foo(7) and Foo(8) occur before the
    // following line.  That means that x_y2points at destructed memory.
    std::cout << "(x2.data,y2.data) = (" << std::get <0>(x_y2).data << ',' <<
        std::get <1> (x_y2).data << ')' << ".  If there's a destructor"
        " before this line that'd mean that this reference is invalid."
        << std::endl;
}
```

This generates

```
constructor
constructor
Called f: (x.data,y.data) = (5,6)
move assignment
move assignment
Finished with f(x,y)
Called f: (x.data,y.data) = (5,6)
Called g: (x.data,y.data) = (5,6)
move assignment
move assignment
Finished with g(f(x,y))
Called f: (x.data,y.data) = (5,6)
Called g: (x.data,y.data) = (5,6)
move
move
Finished with g(f(x,y)) a second time
(x.data,y.data) = (5,6)
constructor
constructor
Called f: (x.data,y.data) = (7,8)
Called g: (x.data,y.data) = (7,8)
destructor
destructor
(x2.data,y2.data) = (7,8).  If there's a destructor before this line that'd mean that this reference is invalid.
destructor
destructor
destructor
destructor
```

Comment: So, assignment cannot be elided under the standard.  By storing the intermediate values into `Foo f2` and `Foo f3` instead of back into `foo` we reduce total move-operations down to 3 from 5.  @Agnew's implicit suggestion of taking `Foo` instead of `Foo&&` parameters actually increases the `move` count by 2, because function parameters may not be elided into outputs in any case.

Comment: What happens if you do `return foo;` instead of `return std::move(foo);` in f() and g()? This should allow NRVO to happen. It will not fix `foo=f(std::move(foo));` but it should avoid one move assignment in `foo=g(f(std::move(foo)));`

Comment: @FredericLachasse In general, that's a good idea, but in this case the code does not do the NRVO and then calls the copy constructor.  The issue is that we're returning a function argument, which the standard says the NRVO does not apply to in 12.8.31.  If we returned a new variable in f or g, then I'd 100% agree with you.

Comment: If the functions are returning inputs, maybe they should return by rref instead of by value?  That would elide the moves, though makes accidental UB easier.

Comment: @MooingDuck Funny enough, that seems to work.  In general, I wouldn't want to return by rref because the memory gets freed on function exit.  However, since the memory is allocated outside the function call, it seems like it's doing the right thing.  Though, I don't understand part of your comment.  What is "accidental UB"?

Comment: @wyer33: Since `f` and `g` aren't returning a reference to local variables, it's a non-issue.  They're returning references to variables in the _caller's_ callstack.  Someone could accidentally cause UB if they wrote `Foo&& t = g(f(Foo()));`, which would create a variable, call `f` with it, then call `g`, and then destroy the temporary, and then attempts to use `t` which would be undefined behavior (usually a crash).  It's safe if they write `Foo t = ...` though.

Comment: @MooingDuck Sounds good.  I updated the question with the code that demonstrates all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @MooingDuck's suggestion, it's actually possible to return an rref from the functions.  Generally, this would be a really bad idea, but since the memory is allocated outside of the function, it becomes a non-issue.  Then, the number of moves is dramatically reduced.  Unfortunately, if someone tries to assign the result to an rref, this will cause undefined behavior.  All of the code and results are below.

For the single argument case:

```c++
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    // Add some data to see if it gets moved correctly
    int data;

    Foo() : data(0) {
        std::cout << "default constructor" << std::endl; 
    } 
    Foo(int const & data_) : data(data_) {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl; 
    } 
    Foo(Foo && x) {
        data = x.data;
        std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(Foo const & x) {
        data = x.data;
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo & operator = (Foo && x) {
        data = x.data;
        std::cout << "move assignment" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
    Foo & operator = (Foo & x) {
        data = x.data;
        std::cout << "copy assignment" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
};

Foo && f(Foo && foo) {
    std::cout << "Called f: foo.data = " << foo.data << std::endl;
    return std::move(foo);
}

Foo && g(Foo && foo) {
    std::cout << "Called g: foo.data = " << foo.data << std::endl;
    return std::move(foo);
}

int main() {
    Foo foo(5);
    foo = f(std::move(foo));
    std::cout << "Finished with f(foo)" << std::endl;
    foo = g(f(std::move(foo)));
    std::cout << "Finished with g(f(foo))" << std::endl;
    Foo foo2 = g(f(std::move(foo)));
    std::cout << "Finished with g(f(foo)) a second time" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "foo2.data = " << foo2.data << std::endl;
    // Now, break it.
    Foo && foo3 = g(f(Foo(4)));  
    // Notice that the destuctor for Foo(4) occurs before the following line.
    // That means that foo3 points at destructed memory.
    std::cout << "foo3.data = " << foo3.data << ".  If there's a destructor"
        " before this line that'd mean that this reference is invalid."
        << std::endl;
}
```

This generates

```
constructor
Called f: foo.data = 5
move assignment
Finished with f(foo)
Called f: foo.data = 5
Called g: foo.data = 5
move assignment
Finished with g(f(foo))
Called f: foo.data = 5
Called g: foo.data = 5
move
Finished with g(f(foo)) a second time
foo2.data = 5
constructor
Called f: foo.data = 4
Called g: foo.data = 4
destructor
foo3.data = 4.  If there's a destructor before this line that'd mean that this reference is invalid.
destructor
destructor
```

In the multi-argument case

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

// This comes from the N3802 proposal for C++
template <typename F, typename Tuple, size_t... I>
decltype(auto) apply_impl(F&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}
template <typename F, typename Tuple>
decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, Tuple&& t) {
    using Indices = 
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>;
    return apply_impl(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t), Indices{});
}

// Now, for our example
struct Foo {
    // Add some data to see if it gets moved correctly
    int data;

    Foo() : data(0) {
        std::cout << "default constructor" << std::endl; 
    } 
    Foo(int const & data_) : data(data_) {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl; 
    } 
    Foo(Foo && x) {
        data = x.data;
        std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(Foo const & x) {
        data = x.data;
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo & operator = (Foo && x) {
        std::cout << "move assignment" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
    Foo & operator = (Foo & x) {
        std::cout << "copy assignment" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
};

std::tuple <Foo&&,Foo&&> f(Foo && x,Foo && y) {
    std::cout << "Called f: (x.data,y.data) = (" << x.data << ',' <<
        y.data << ')' << std::endl;
    return std::tuple <Foo&&,Foo&&> (std::move(x),std::move(y));
}

std::tuple <Foo&&,Foo&&> g(Foo && x,Foo && y) {
    std::cout << "Called g: (x.data,y.data) = (" << x.data << ',' <<
        y.data << ')' << std::endl;
    return std::tuple <Foo&&,Foo&&> (std::move(x),std::move(y));
}

int main() {
    Foo x(5),y(6);
    std::tie(x,y) = f(std::move(x),std::move(y));
    std::cout << "Finished with f(x,y)" << std::endl;
    std::tie(x,y) = apply(g,f(std::move(x),std::move(y)));
    std::cout << "Finished with g(f(x,y))" << std::endl;
    std::tuple <Foo,Foo> x_y = apply(g,f(std::move(x),std::move(y)));
    std::cout << "Finished with g(f(x,y)) a second time" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(x.data,y.data) = (" << std::get <0>(x_y).data << ',' <<
        std::get <1> (x_y).data << ')' << std::endl;
    // Now, break it.
    std::tuple <Foo&&,Foo&&> x_y2 = apply(g,f(Foo(7),Foo(8)));  
    // Notice that the destuctors for Foo(7) and Foo(8) occur before the
    // following line.  That means that x_y2points at destructed memory.
    std::cout << "(x2.data,y2.data) = (" << std::get <0>(x_y2).data << ',' <<
        std::get <1> (x_y2).data << ')' << ".  If there's a destructor"
        " before this line that'd mean that this reference is invalid."
        << std::endl;
}
```

This generates

```
constructor
constructor
Called f: (x.data,y.data) = (5,6)
move assignment
move assignment
Finished with f(x,y)
Called f: (x.data,y.data) = (5,6)
Called g: (x.data,y.data) = (5,6)
move assignment
move assignment
Finished with g(f(x,y))
Called f: (x.data,y.data) = (5,6)
Called g: (x.data,y.data) = (5,6)
move
move
Finished with g(f(x,y)) a second time
(x.data,y.data) = (5,6)
constructor
constructor
Called f: (x.data,y.data) = (7,8)
Called g: (x.data,y.data) = (7,8)
destructor
destructor
(x2.data,y2.data) = (7,8).  If there's a destructor before this line that'd mean that this reference is invalid.
destructor
destructor
destructor
destructor
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that what you need is not a mechanism to move back and forth a value through a function call, since references do that adequately, but a device to compose functions working that way.

```
template <void f(Foo &), void g(Foo &)>
void compose2(Foo &v){
   f(v);
   g(v);
}
```

Of course, you could make this more generic on the parameter type.

```
template <typename T, void f(T&), void (...G)(T&)>
void compose(T &v){
  f(v);
  compose2<T,G...>(v);
}

template <typename T>
void compose(Foo &){
}
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

//... above template definitions for compose elided


struct Foo {
  int x;
};

void f(Foo &v){
  v.x++;
}

void g(Foo &v){
  v.x *= 2;
}

int main(){
  Foo v = { 9 };

  compose<Foo, f, g, f, g>(v);

  std::cout << v.x << "\n"; // output "42"
}
```

Note that you could even parameterize the template on the procedure prototype, but at this time on my machine, only clang++ (v3.5) seems to accept it, g++ (4.9.1) doesn't like it.

Comment: Technically, yes.  I really want to this work with multiple arguments as well, which is sort of moving the goal posts.  I explain more about this in an update to the question.

Comment: There's no need for `f` and `g` to be template parameters. Just make `compose` take a `std::initializer_list<void (*)(T &)>`, and call `compose<Foo>({ f, g, f, g }, v)`. And that can easily be extended to handle multiple parameters, by making `T` a template parameter pack. (But I may be missing something here. If composition of this form is feasible, then why not just write `f(v); g(v); f(v); g(v);`?)

Comment: @hvd OP wants to be able to compose these procedures, maybe in order to pass the composition to some other bit of code?

Comment: @hvd and feel free to edit my answer if there's a place which deserve to be enhanced or fixed.

Comment: @didierc In that case, I'd use a lamba: you can pass `[](Foo &v) { f(v); g(v); f(v); g(v); }` to any function taking `void(*)(Foo &)`. I guess that's also a bit of a comment to the OP, not just to you, though. It's not clear to me that your answer is the best way to address the OP's question, but that's in part because the reason for the question is not clear to me. I'll refrain from editing, I may be misunderstanding the OP's reason for this entirely.

Comment: @hvd well,that's indeed a simpler way to do it! Sometimes things are so obvious that I just cannot see them.

Comment: @hvd That's an interesting and concise idea.  Really, the issue with composability has to do with chaining a bunch of math operations together.  Basically, in BLAS, we have vector operations like `axpy(a,x,y)` where `y<-a*x+y` and `scal(a,x)` where `x<-a*x`.  These arguments are passed by reference.  If we want to set `y=2*x+2*y`, we can chain this by hand, `scal(2,y); axpy(2,x,y);`  Nevertheless, it's nice to just compose them with `y=axpy(2,x,scal(2,move(y)));`  This also has the effect of stating that we're modifying the memory of `y` since we're forced to call `move` on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without move if you use a little bit of indirection and compiler optimizations:

```
void do_f(Foo & foo); // The code that used to in in f

inline Foo f(Foo foo)
{
    do_f(foo);
    return foo; // This return will be optimized away due to inlining
}
```

Comment: Due to inlining or NRVO? I think NRVO will optimise away the return value and inlining will replace the call of `f(foo)` with a call to `do_f(foo)`, won't it?

Comment: Well, one of them, it depends on the way you look at it. If you look at the inlining first, it would replace the call with `Foo temp_foo = foo; do_f(temp_foo); foo = temp_foo;` which the compiler would optimize to `do_f(foo);`. But you can look at it the other way around as the return being optimized away with NRVO first and then the inlining would take place. In both cases, the resulting code would be the same.

Comment: NRVO will not be applied to function parameters. I.e., the object `foo` will be *moved* into the return value, and that move may not be elided.